# translating wordpress theme new added strings

Tags: wordpress, poedit

I'm trying to translate twenty ten based child theme, I have modifided the single-loop.php with a custom snippet, that shows next and previous arrows...

My issue is that this string (next and previous text) cant be translated... the replacement doesnt occur with this specific string. I do all the process of detecting the string and creating all with poedit, but does not work. all other strings do translate OK.

I edited the php file single-loop.php by adding a next-previous snippet.

```
<?php add_filter('wp_get_object_terms', 'my_custom_post_navigation', 4, 99); ?>
<div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
    <div class="nav-previous">
        <?php next_post_link( '<span class="meta-nav"> %link </span>', __( '&#9668; Previous','Previous post link', 'category','twentyten') , TRUE ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-next">
        <?php previous_post_link( '<span class="meta-nav"> %link </span>', __( 'Next &#9658;','Next post link', 'category', 'twentyten') , TRUE ); ?>
    </div>
</div><!-- #nav-above -->
<?php remove_filter('wp_get_object_terms', 'my_custom_post_navigation', 99); ?>

<!-- END .featandnav  of Featured and Navigation container DIV  -->
```

Then I scanned all the php files with poedit and the strings appear: I translated them (`Next &#9658;` - and -`&#9668; Previous`) using poedit.. but then, even that I uploaded the files to the theme language folder, this string does not translate, but all the others original of the theme, do translate...

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not using the `__()` function correctly does that. Such as passing it four arguments when it only takes two. See its signature [in the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2).